# Change DNS Server through registry?

Tags: windows-xp, dns, google-public-dns

How can I change/switch my DNS server IP address by a registry script?

For example, I want to change to Google DNS Server (IP: 8.8.8.8) often and when I  need to check my internet usage I need to switch back to the default service provider's DNS Server.

So I need to create two reg scripts one for setting the DNS to nil (Default) and the other for changing it to google DNS.

Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

Rather than using a .reg file you can use the NETSH command line util, e.g.

```
netsh interface ip set dns "Local Area Connection" static 192.168.0.200
```

taken from and more info available [here](http://www.petri.co.il/configure_tcp_ip_from_cmd.htm)

You can then create .bat files with the 2 different settings you want